# How to dynamically choose and set class variable in VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net

I want to set a variable in a class. But I want to dynamically choose which variable to set.

In PHP :

```
<?PHP
class Foo {
    var $Bar="Blah";
}

$ClassVar = new Foo();
$Variable = "Bar";
$ClassVar->$Variable = "Poo";
echo "Output : ".$ClassVar->Bar;
?>
```

**Output : Poo**

I want to do the same in VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB you’d use a dictionary to achieve this.

```
Dim x As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()

x.Add("Bar", "Blah")

Dim variable = "Bar"
x(variable) = "Poo"
Console.WriteLine(x("Bar"))
```

Although this is more reminiscent of the PHP `array`. It *is* actually possible to get the same effect in VB as in your PHP code, using reflection. But VB is a different language and in VB you’d normally not write such a code. Even more strongly: when you find yourself writing such code in VB, it’s almost always a sign of a serious flaw in your code design.

But just for completeness’ sake:

```
Dim obj As New Foo()
CallByName(obj, "Bar", CallType.Let, "Poo")
```

However, this only works when `Bar` is in fact a property, not a variable (it also works with a variable but that’s more difficult still).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm in the process of writing generic text validate functions. I wanted to use this to validate the value. "Bar" is a property in my class. If not using this, then do you recommend another way of doing this? BTW, my class has 130 properties.

Comment: Your class has 130 properties? Now **that** is a certain indication that your code architecture is fundamentally flawed. No class should ever have anywhere near that many properties.